# Flex/AIR: Export DataGrid to Excel with multiple sheets

Tags: apache-flex, excel, datagrid

I have an AIR application with two DataGrids that I would like to export to Excel. I've found the [as3xls](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/) library, but it can only handle one sheet (as per the comments). Ideally, I'd like to export both DataGrids into separate sheets in the same workbook.

The AIR application is running entirely on the user's desktop and doesn't have a connection to any server, so the solution would need to be Flex/AIR only. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout AIR 2.0's NativeProcess class, it let's you call external/system commands.  I'm calling a Python script to merge 2 worksheets created by AS3XLS.  The biggest issue is that AS3XLS writes a lot of garbage.  Am going to try exporting the datagrids as CSV and then let Python's XLRD/XLWT modules do the Excel stuff.

Comment: Thanks, that might be useful in the future. However, at the moment, I can't expect the client to have Python installed, and I don't want to add more than necessary to the application installation. So currently I only let them export the current view to the Excel document.